# glibc documentation and endianness

Tags: linux, unix, endianness, glibc, systems-programming

[glibc documentation on process completion status](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Process-Completion-Status.html) states that the macro WEXITSTATUS returns the low order 8 bytes of the completion status.

> Macro: int WEXITSTATUS (int status)
>
> If WIFEXITED is true of status, this macro returns the low-order 8 bits of the exit status value from the child process.

However, `/usr/include/sys/wait.h` says:

```
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)    __WEXITSTATUS (__WAIT_INT (status))
```

And, `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` mentions:

```
/* If WIFEXITED(STATUS), the low-order 8 bits of the status.  */
#define __WEXITSTATUS(status)   (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
```

Unless my endian-ness concepts are all messed up, how is this the **low-order** 8 bits? Or is libc assuming that the data is kept in a small-endian way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an endianness issue. Endianness refers to how the data is stored in memory; on either a big- or little-endian machine, `(((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)` extracts bits 15 through 8, i.e. the 8th through 15th least significant bits of the `status` macro argument.

The documentation and comments are confusing because status refers to two different things.

The process that exits returns a status code. This exit status has type `int` in the source (either as return value from `main`, or as argument to `exit`), however, the value should be between 0 and 255.

The `wait` and `waitpid` system calls also provide a `status` back to the caller. This status is different; the low-order 8 bits of the original exit status are now in bits 15 through 8. I assume the documentation says WEXITSTATUS returns the "low-order 8 bits" because that was the packing of the exit status from the perspective of the exiting process.

Comment: The documentation says "low order 8 bits" because, although the child process can have any `int` return value, in a Posix environment, only the least significant 8 bits of that status are returned to the parent. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/_exit.html